# Answer being a real answer or a comment

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, behavior

Apart from the fact that the answer is a duplicate and the proper behavior is to close the question. There is one user commenting on every answer saying that the answer is not an answer but a comment.

I completely disagree with that, as those answer are maybe not the best quality, but I don't think is a good idea to go confusing user about it.

The post is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093382/open-text-file-in-javascript

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I was trying to tell him, but I started to doubt about it. What is the correct way of acting in this situation?

Comment: You have a point, but the overarching issue here is that there's a duplicate that has been identified and that has a much better answer. Not sure whether it's worth fighting over this specific case.

Comment: @Pekka웃 But what if he does that in normal questions? New users could get confused (except if he is right and should be comments)

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely worth discussing the basic issue (if it hasn't been done already, in which case someone will surely point us to a duplicate eventually.)

Comment: Eh, this is a programming site; we shouldn't have to explain why "you do not want a web page to access your hard drive". It's an answer. Not a great one, but an answer nonetheless.

Comment: @Yannis: If the NSA and botnet.ua already have everything on my hard drive (at least on most of my Windows VMs), why shouldn't everyone else get access?

Comment: Does that guy even have an answer to the question, or did he just feel like commenting on each answer telling them it's a commenT?

Comment: Maybe the tendency for some poor answers to show up as comments leads some to consider any poor answer to be a comment. Personally, I agree with you it's a answer (albeit a poor one). But I've had the shoe on the other foot myself, where I believed a posted "answer" to not be an answer at all, but rather more appropriate as a comment while someone else disagreed. Oh well. Opinions vary...that's why we have voting. It's pointless to try to debate semantics of this nature.

Comment: @McAdam331: What's the link between the two? Are you suggesting that one requires an answer to a question before having the right to write comments on it? Because, if so, you're wrong.

Comment: I'm ok with answers if they correctly state "it can't be done". How else would you checkmark no-can-do questions as answered so they don't hang around in the unanswered queue forever?  **In this case you might also state the obvious** "...because reading files from your hard drive opens your private files to theft."

Answer (score 19):

I'm not familiar with JavaScript but I agree with the comment stating that it should be an answer.

The user who answered the question should have mentioned some of the reasons and elaborated more on it.

I'll give you an example where I differentiate between a comment and an answer:

> Why my loop is not working?
>
> `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++);` 
>             `System.out.println("Number :", i);`

A comment would be "Remove ; from the end of the loop". But if there exist an answer (assuming the question is not closed for *a simple typographical error* for the sake of the example), I expect it to be more detailed:

"Remove ; from the end of the loop, as it's equivalent for writing a `for` loop without a body, it's the same as writing `for (...) { }` [link to a documentation if available]..."

I think that the correct way is asking the user for clarifying his answer, adding more details and elaborate more on it.

In other cases where the answer is far from being an answer, I would downvote, explaining my downvote and maybe vote to delete, depending on its quality.

Comment: Agree. The correct behavior should be to tell the user to improve the answer (and maybe downvote or close). But I think telling the user that is not an asnwer but a comment is confusing.

Comment: Your answer reads like it should the answer in question should be a comment instead of an answer. Is the following a typo? *stating that it should[n't] be an answer.*

Comment: The problem I have with saying that this guy's answer isn't an answer is that what people will take away from this is that they should flag such answers as Not An Answer. Those flags will all be denied, because according to the moderator definition, those *are* answers. I 100% agree that they're not *good* answers, but they are definite attempts to answer the question.

Comment: _'A comment would be "Remove ; from the end of the loop".'_ No! That would be a [bad] answer-in-comments. Answers do not go in comments. Answers go in the answers. Even if they're short and crap (and if they're _too_ short, _do not post them_ and leave it to someone else to do a better job).

Comment: What @Chris Hayes said. People need to stop conflating the SE definition of "comment" with their own (which, apparently, goes something like "does not answer the question to my satisfaction").

Comment: It really depends, sometimes a short answer in the comments can really help OP, even after the question will be closed, sometimes it's indeed better to leave it for someone else. After all, Stack Overflow is there for us to help each other.

Answer (score 12):

IMHO it is an answer because at a question asking *how to do ...* it answers *you can't because ...*. So it would be an error to flag it as Not An Answer. At best flag will be disputed, at worst it would be declined.

But you are right, the *because* part should be more elaborated for the answer to be a good one. That means it is a poor answer that deserved to :

- be downvoted (it has been)
- be left a comment to say why it is a poor answer (there's one)

Once both conditions are met, it is up to you to see if you want to downvote more but besides that there's nothing more to do.

Answer (score -4):

> Apart from the fact that the answer is a duplicate and the proper behavior is to close the question.

Ignoring that fact is kind of the problem.

#### This is the problem, people are arguing if something is an answer or a comment instead of whether the disputed answer should have existed at all!

This question's root cause was about the *behavior* of posting *comments as answers*, I contend that the behaviour that should be questioned is **why did they answer this at all?**

Because focusing on that behavior would benefit the community more than the whether *comments as answers* behavior is valid a behavior that has already been addressed and is not a hard problem to solve because there is a mechanism to handle that. `Flag as Not An Answer`, `Downvote` and move on.

Comment: Well, yes--it's a duplicate. But to be fair to this meta question...The question is about how to handle similar non-duplicate questions rather than this specific (duplicate) question.

Comment: questions that attract *comment as answer* answers always qualify for multiple close reasons; duplicates, too broad, too opinion based are the top choices for these type of questions as they are usually short useless and vague to begin with.

Comment: OK, invalid questions should be closed. But "It can't be done" is a valid answer to some valid questions.

Comment: that is not the point here, whether it can be done or not, the valid behavior is to not answer duplicates.

Comment: I understand and accept your point :-) ... We should close duplicate questions and link to the original question/answer. But isn't SysDragon's meta question here about whether any valid (non-duplicate) question can be answered simply: "It can't be done because..." ? Or maybe I'm tired and misunderstanding the point of his question. Cheers!

Comment: Would it be better if we created a question for the purposes of this topic that's neither off-topic nor a duplicate and built a meta discussion around that instead? Whether the answer should have been posted or not is irrelevant; the fact is that **it has already been posted**. If the answer was a link-only answer pointing to the dupe, or a stolen copy of an answer from the dupe, fine, delete it after-the-fact. But the answers we're talking about have nothing to do with the dupe that was found afterward. You can't blame people for answering questions not realizing they were dupes.